# CRF module not found

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, crf

I am trying to run a code on visual studio code (jupyter notebook).
When I try to run this:

```py
from crf import apply_crf

y_pred = apply_crf(ori_img1, y_pred)
```

It shows an error that `crf` is not found. Can someone help me?

I tried installing crf. I searched all the answers on this website but nothing works.

Comment: _I tried installing crf_ Was it **successful**?  Saying that you "tried" is vague.

Comment: installation was successful. but the error exists. module not found.

Comment: I'm guessing you have two (or more) installations of python on your system, and vs code/pip do not agree on which installation of python to use.

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install the module.

Comment: yes i am using vscode python 3.7.8. i used command !pip3 install crf to install crf. it says Requirement already satisfied: crf in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1a1). 
then i use command from crf import apply_crf 
but still gives error crf module not found.

Comment: Show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the following:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/pydensecrf.git
```